# SQL Order, Limit and Random

Tags: sql, random, limit

Say I have 10 objects in an SQL table. Each has a Title and a Rating. Say the rating are as below:

Now I need to show the top 5 (with Limit) with rating of 5 stars. However there are 7 with rating of 5 stars, and When I order by rating I always get the same 5 objects.

I need to order by rating, limit by 5, but randomise in the case that there are more then 5 objects with the same rating (could be 5 start, could be 4 star etc.)

This code should work in other scenarios too. For example I might have 2 objects with 5 stars, and 4 with 4 stars. Between the 4 of 4 stars it must be randomised too to show 3 of them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a relation with random order.

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
```

And then apply your query with this relation (nested SELECT)

```
SELECT tab2.title FROM
  (SELECT * FROM table
  ORDER BY RAND())
AS tab2
ORDER BY rating
```

I didnt test it, but it should work on mysql